# node server on EC2 machine taking 10+ seconds to respond with bundle files to lo

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bundle

node server on EC2 machine taking 10+ seconds to respond with bundle files to load the html page. The app running on node server is an angular 5 app. If i access the bundle files individually from the link directly they open up very quickly.

Comment: What file sizes / quantities do you have? Also have you considered hosting as many of the static files on S3 if it's a webapp?

Comment: The files are only 30-50kb. It's an angular 5 app. I'm called it into an angularjs app  via node server.